# jquery-ui ui-draggable not dragging

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a set of html elements that should use the ui-draggable class from jquery-ui. I need to update all of the jquery-ui elements dynamically. This program renders html after the page has been loaded.

```
<div id="s1" class="draggyBox-small">Loop Body</div>
```

I expect that when I click on the element and drag it the class should get updated to ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging. There aren't any error messages. I've tried hard coding the class on the elements

```
<div id="s1" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable">Loop Body</div>
```

```
<div id="t1" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
```

A function like the one shown below updates selected inputs

```
function update_draggy_boxes(){
      $("[class^=draggy]").draggable();
    }
```

I need to update all of the elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's also interesting in which sequence do you call the scripts...

Comment: https://github.com/EvanGertis/Selected-Topics/blob/main/wordMatch/Section5_3.html

Comment: Newly added items will not have Draggable initialized after the fact. You will have to initialize after the item is added or when it's added. Run your `update_draggy_boxes()`.